# communication between host and iframe application

Tags: angular, html, iframe, postmessage, angular7

I have a UI application built in angular 7. This application displays another application in its iframe (the child application displayed in iframe is also built in angular 7).

[image]

I need to pass some data to iframe. I have gone through few posts which talks about events and HTML5 postMessage. but could not find any clear solution or code sample for angular application.

Comment: The only way to do this is to make your iframe application know what you pass maybe by using url params.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ngx-post-message](https://github.com/apoterenko/ngx-post-message) npm package - they have some examples in the repo README file.